# Media query for mobile is controlling desktop style

Tags: css, styles, media-queries

I'm building the site for a desktop with the CSS below for an element. . .

```
.give-donation-level-btn {
    font-size: 16px;
```

When I apply the media query for mobile, it controls the desktop style as well.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .give-donation-level-btn {
    font-size: .9rem !important;
}
```

With the !important declaration for the query, I thought that style would be applied only to screens ≤. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end of your media query part, is it juste a copy paste issue ? Can you edit if yes please ? ^^ Same for the first css code

Comment: if this is an issue just caused by the missing bracket then please remove the question voluntarily (`caused by typos`).

Comment: Oh man! Definitely a cut and paste typo. The code still doesn't work with the bracket added. So strange.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing out a curly bracket.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .give-donation-level-btn {
    font-size: .9rem !important;
  }
}
```

Don't worry, this only happens to the best programmers ;).

I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Oh man! Definitely a cut and paste typo. The code still doesn't work with the bracket added. So strange.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *device-width* was the culprit. *max-device-width* worked, though I'm uncertain why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).